# Multiple Inheritance levels in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a class hierarchy with multiple levels, like so:

```
abstract class BaseElement {
  private String name;
}

abstract class BaseShape extends BaseElement {
  private String attr2;
}

abstract class BaseQuadrangle extends BaseShape {
  private String attr3;

  private String attr4;
}

class Square extends BaseQuadrangle {
  private String attr5;
}

class Rectangle extends BaseQuadrangle {
  private int attr6;
}

abstract class BaseTriangle extends BaseShape {
  private int attr7;
}

class RightTriangle extends BaseTriangle {
  private int attr9;
}

class EquilateralTriangle extends BaseTriangle {
  private int attr10;
}
```

This hierarchy exists so I don't have to repeat the definition of common attributes on the concrete classes.

I want to have a single `Shape` table with all the attributes that holds all the records, to facilitate querying.

I initially mapped it as:

```
@MappedSuperClass
abstract class BaseElement {
  private String name;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "shape_type")
@Table(name = "shape")
abstract class BaseShape extends BaseElement {
  private String attr2;
}

@MappedSuperClass
abstract class BaseQuadrangle extends BaseShape {
  private String attr3;

  private String attr4;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("square")
class Square extends BaseQuadrangle {
  private String attr5;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("rectangle")
class Rectangle extends BaseQuadrangle {
  private int attr6;
}

@MappedSuperClass
abstract class BaseTriangle extends BaseShape {
  private int attr7;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("right_triangle")
class RightTriangle extends BaseTriangle {
  private int attr9;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("equilateral_triangle")
class EquilateralTriangle extends BaseTriangle {
  private int attr10;
}
```

However, this mapping resulted in 2 tables being created, `Quadrangle` and `Triangle`, which is not the desired outcome.

How can I achieve the single table result?

Comment: Are you sure your two tables were not `BaseQuadrangle` and `BaseTriangle`?  I can see where those might come from, but not `Quadrangle` and `Triangle`.

Comment: It puzzled me as well, but that's what I got.

Comment: Are you sure, then, that your DB was generated from the same classes you've presented in the question?  I could believe that it was generated from a version of the persistence unit that named those classes `Quadrangle` and `Triangle`, without "Base".  Ultimately, it might not matter, but if your DB structure is not keeping up with your persistence unit (re-)definitions then that's a separate problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that the DB structure was generated from the version of your persistence unit that you show, the issue appears to be that you have non-entity classes between the root entity and some of the leaf entities of your inheritance tree.  The JPA specifications do allow this, but they do not directly address what effect it has on the single-table strategy.  I am nevertheless a bit surprised by the specifics you describe, and I would be inclined to call it a flaw in your persistence provider.  Not that that helps you.

Given that you are using the single-table inheritance strategy, however, I don't see what's to be gained by using mapped superclasses in the middle of the tree instead of entities.  I would just make these entities.  It should not be a problem that they are abstract (though bugs are possible here, too).  This is what I have in mind:

```
@MappedSuperClass
abstract class BaseElement {
  private String name;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "shape_type")
@Table(name = "shape")
abstract class BaseShape extends BaseElement {
  private String attr2;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("quadrangle") // should not appear in the DB because abstract
abstract class BaseQuadrangle extends BaseShape {
  private String attr3;

  private String attr4;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("square")
class Square extends BaseQuadrangle {
  private String attr5;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("rectangle")
class Rectangle extends BaseQuadrangle {
  private int attr6;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("triangle") // should not appear in the DB because abstract
abstract class BaseTriangle extends BaseShape {
  private int attr7;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("right_triangle")
class RightTriangle extends BaseTriangle {
  private int attr9;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("equilateral_triangle")
class EquilateralTriangle extends BaseTriangle {
  private int attr10;
}
```

Comment: Apparently, that did the trick. Thanks!